# What is Concept of Idempotent in RestFul WebApi?

Tags: asp.net, .net, web

can anybody explain what is Idempotent in RestFul WebApi and when use it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The **GET**, **PUT**, and **DELETE** methods are said to be ***idempotent***; that is, calling them over and over will produce the same result without any additional side effects. For example, the caller should be able to call the DELETE action
on a specific resource without receiving any errors and without harming the system. If the resource has already been deleted, the caller should not receive an error. The same applies to the PUT action. For a given unique resource
(identified by an element URI), submitting a PUT request should update the resource if it already exists. Or, if it doesn’t exist, the system should create the resource as submitted. In other words, calling PUT over and over produces
the same result without any additional side effects (i.e., the new task will exist in the system per the representation provided by the caller, whether the system had to create a new one or update an existing one).

The **GET** action is also said to be safe. Safe means that nothing in the system is changed at all, which is appropriate for HTTP calls that are meant to query the system for either a collection of resources or for a specific resource. It is important that the idempotency of the service’s **GET**, **PUT**, and **DELETE** operations remain consistent with the HTTP protocol standards. Thus, every effort should be made to ensure those three actions can be called over and
over without error.

Unlike the other three actions, **POST** is ***not considered to be idempotent***. This is because POST is used to create a new instance of the identified resource type for every invocation of the method. Where calling PUT over and over will never result in more than one resource being created or updated, calling POST will result in new resource instances—one for each call. This is appropriate for cases where the system must generate the new resource’s identifier and return it in the response.

***Source:*** [ASP.NET Web API 2: Building a REST Service from Start to Finish](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1484201108)

Comment: Thank you Win , i got it ;)

Comment: What will happen if POST a request over and over to create a record?  Will it give exception second time due to the same record found?

Comment: Best explaination on Stackoverflow so far!